# How to properly align this composition of maps?

Tags: math-mode, align, alignat

I wish to write the composition of two maps in a single equation. Since there are multiple places to be aligned, I tried with `alignat`, but cannot get the align points correct. Below is my current result, as you can see, there is some empty space before the second `\to` arrow. How can I get the alignment correct?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{alignedat}{2}
        \text{something} &\to \text{some other thing} &&\to \text{something else}\\
        x &\mapsto y & a &\mapsto b
    \end{alignedat}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it isn't clear what you want. the space is from the `a` on the 2nd row. Your arrow chains have no natural alignment: the first row only has one item between the arrows, the second row has two (y and a)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I would like the two elements between the two `\mapsto` arrows in the second row two be aligned on the left and right, respectively. Now I'm doing this by adding a `&` between them, but as you said, this would leave an empty space for the `a` in the first row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this, although beware it may over-print without warning if the first row item is not sufficiently long.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{alignedat}{2}
        \text{something} &\to \text{some other thing} &&\to \text{something else}\\
        x &\mapsto y   &&\mathllap{a}\mapsto b
    \end{alignedat}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IEEEeqnarray` (fixing a small glitch).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{r C l r C l}
\text{something} & \to &
  \IEEEeqnarraymulticol{2}{c}{\text{some other thing}\mkern-\thickmuskip} & \to &
  \text{something else} \\
x & \mapsto & y & \mathrm{g} & \mapsto & b
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}

\end{document}
```

I used `\mathrm{g}` to show that there is the right alignment, with the fix.

[image]